# Constraining <p> to the bounds of an angled <div> w/ CSS (JSFiddle link attached)

Tags: css, html, rotation, transform, paragraph

I would like the `<p>` in my document to be contained within an angled `<section>` container so as to create stepped lines for the paragraph. Ideally I'd like the paragraph take the shape of an parallelogram. As it stands, when I rotate my my paragraph so that the lines are horizontal, the paragraph extends beyond the bounds of the `<div>`. See my JSFiddle link below:

http://jsfiddle.net/aredtiefilm/sUymx/2/

When I try overflow options, the best I can do is hide the sections of the paragraph that are outside the `<section>`. I'd like to force the contents of the paragraph to take the shape of the container, without hiding or scrolling.  Is this posible?

Answer (score 0):

Use following css for paragraph element. It will work fine.

MODIFIED CSS :

```
p{
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: That isn't a change to the code, and I'm sure you're aware that wouldn't affect anything. Is there more to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect, but this the best that I think that you can get.
Replace rotate by skew:

```
section{
    color: #4A2583;
    -ms-transform:skewX(10deg); 
    -moz-transform:skewX(106deg); 
    -webkit-transform:skewX(10deg); 
    -o-transform:skewX(10deg);
    transform:skewX(10deg);
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    left: 200px;
}
```

You don't need to style the p, it's useless. (You can not rotate the individual lines, you can only rotate it as a block)

You need to limit the angle because the letters are being also skewed, if you do it too much that will be ugly.

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sUymx/4/)